# How to get real web trace data for academic research?

Tags: web, networking, server, trace, zipf

I want to collect some web access data for academic research on network, it should follows the well-known zipf-distribution, but I don't know where can I get it.

The newer the better for this data. I found some link in some old paper, since many papers are too old, the link on the papers is being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions for getting web trace data would be:

- **Public Datasets:** Look for publicly available datasets from academic institutions or similar:

1. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php
2. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

- **Organizations:** Contact organizations that might be willing to send you datasets under certain conditions.
- **Government Resources:** A lot of government agencies release datasets for research.
- **Internet Archive:** The [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) maybe has historical web data which could be useful.

Remember to follow the datas relevance to the zipf distribution and the ethical and legal guidelines of using web trace data.